# Why is my with statement not executing correctly?

Tags: python, loops

I have a code, written as shown below, which comprises of a `with` block.

```
alleles=[]
pop = 1 + 4
snp=[]
# read in input file
with open("input.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        alleles.append(line.split()[2]+line.split()[1])   # risk first, then ref. keep risk as second allele

    snp = [{"riskall": line[1],"weight": float(line[4]),"freq": float(line[pop]), 
            line[1]+line[1]:(2*float(line[4]),(float(line[pop])*float(line[pop]))),
            line[2]+line[1]:(float(line[4]),(2*(((1-float(line[pop]))*(float(line[pop])))))),
            line[2]+line[2]:(0, ((1-float(line[pop]))*((1-float(line[pop])))))} for line in map(lambda x: x.split(),f)]
```

Strangely enough, the `snp` assignment simply does not work, resulting in an empty array. The same occurs if I switch the places of my `for` loop and the `snp` assignment, where the latter works fine but the former does not happen.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm quite sure the indentation is correct..

Comment: When you finish the loop, the file is "empty" (it does not have any more lines). That's why `map(lambda x: x.split(),f)` returns an empty list. There is literally nothing left to split. Consider reading all the lines into a list and then processing them in one or two loops - or reading the contents twice.

Comment: `lambda x: x.split()` could be `x.split`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually, `str.split`.

Comment: _"comprises of a with loop"_ I'm confused: Are you saying that the `with` keyword creates a loop, similar to what you'd get with a `for` or a `while`? If so, then that's not correct.

Comment: @DYZ thanks very much, that makes sense. Would there be a solution where I do not store the file in memory? I am afraid that it would become slow when working with larger inputs. Would reading the contents twice have just a small impact on performance?

Comment: Build `alleles` and `snp` in the same loop. Consider splitting each line once into a list and then recombining the bits and pieces as needed.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I guess I shall just do that.

Comment: @DYZ aw yes. Got blinded by the clunky `map(lambda ...`